# Ansible Standard Loop Not working

Tags: ansible

I have written the following ansible script

```
---
# Playbook file: loopplay.yml
-
    name: loopplay
    hosts: centos2
    tags:
        - loopplay
    tasks:
        -
            name: looptask
            user:
                name: "{{ item }}"
                state: present
                groups: "wheel"
            loop:
                - testuser1
                - testuser2
```

However, I keep on getting the following error:

> The error appears to have been in
>   '/opt/ansible-projects/test_5af9a55448f0c8003531a07d_loopproject/loopplay.yml':
>   line 10, column 13, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the
>   exact syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> - name: looptask ^ here

Can someone let me know where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you should fix the indentation first.

here is a sample yml to get you started fixing your own:

```
- name: loopplay
  hosts: localhost
  tags:
    - loopplay
  tasks:
    - name: print something
      debug:
        msg: "test msg"
```

Comment: Fix exactly what? The code in question is correctly indented (it might not suit your taste, but there is nothing syntactically wrong with it).